# MKMapView Current Location Display

Tags: iphone

I am Getting the pin which Display Current Location in english but i want to display in Different language so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, which display you mean? There's only a flashing blue indicator where the user is (I believe, I'm not 100% sure)?